# Access local file path in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have added a folder name Resources and under it there is another folder name File inside the file folder there are two xml files which i'm trying to parse. When i give pathforResource method name to my Resources folder it shows path is null. How can i access the two xml file from these folders? 
Resources->File->text.xml.
My code is this,

```c
    NSMutableArray *aryXMLName = [NSMutableArray new];
    [aryXMLName addObject:@"text.xml"];
    [aryXMLName addObject:@"test1.xml"];

    for(NSString *str in aryXMLName){
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:str ofType:@"Resources"];
        NSLog(@"Path : %@",path);
        NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

        if ([str isEqualToString:@"text.xml"]) {
            if (data == nil)
                return;
            NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSLog(@"string: %@", str);
            NSDictionary *xmlDoc = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:str];
            NSLog(@"dictionary: %@", xmlDoc);
        }else if ([str isEqualToString:@"test1.xml"]){
            if (data == nil)
                return;
            NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSLog(@"string: %@", str);
            NSDictionary *xmlDoc = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:str];
            NSLog(@"dictionary: %@", xmlDoc);
        }


    }
```

The scenario is like this,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OY0L.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this code:

```
      NSMutableArray *aryXMLName = [NSMutableArray new];
      [aryXMLName addObject:@"test"];
      [aryXMLName addObject:@"text1"];

       for(NSString *str in aryXMLName){

              NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:str ofType:@"xml"];
              NSLog(@"Path : %@",path);
              NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

              if ([str isEqualToString:@"test"]) {

                   if (data == nil)
                       return;
                   NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                   NSLog(@"string: %@", str);
                   NSDictionary *xmlDoc = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:str];
                   NSLog(@"dictionary: %@", xmlDoc);

              }else if ([str isEqualToString:@"text1"]){

                   if (data == nil)
                      return;
                   NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                   NSLog(@"string: %@", str);
                   NSDictionary *xmlDoc = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:str];
                   NSLog(@"dictionary: %@", xmlDoc);
              }

        }
```

Comment: again its giving null in path. @mayursinh zala

Comment: you have to remove file extension from it's name. check edited answer.

Comment: Bro once when loop runs it gives path but when it goes to the else condition it show null path for second item in the list. @mayursinh zala

Comment: i edited my answer, just replace code with edited answer.

Comment: can i run one loop for both of these files? @mayursinh zala